# Rigorously distinguishing torque from work, or, a more accurate algebraic structure for dimensional analysis

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, dimensional-analysis, unit-of-measure

The algebraic structure underlying dimensional analysis is commonly said to be a finitely generated Abelian group, whose generating set is the set of base units (e.g. length, time, mass, charge, and temperature).  The problem with this is that there exist pairs of derived units that are not commensurable despite having the same decomposition, with the canonical example being work and torque: both decompose to $T^{−2}ML^{2}$ (aka force times distance) but it doesn't make sense to add them.

It occurs to me that the problem with *this* pair of units is conflating two kinds of multiplication.  Work is more accurately described as the line integral of force over a path, which is a generalized *dot* product; torque is the *cross* product of force with the distance between the point where the force is applied and the axis of rotation.  So we ought to say that work decomposes to $T^{-2}ML\cdot L$ whereas torque decomposes to $T^{-2}ML\times L$ and they are not the same.

The question is then:

1. Does conflation of different kinds of multiplication account for *all* cases where standard dimensional analysis gives the same decomposition for two (or more) different, incommensurable derived quantities?
2. What is the algebraic structure I'm using when I say things like "$T^{-2}ML\times L$", and what are its properties?  It has three operators (scalar, dot, and cross product; or, if we prefer bivectors to pseudovectors, then wedge product instead of cross product) and we now have to keep track of whether the base units have scalar or vector nature.  One of the operators is non-commutative, but distributivity and (if we use wedge product) associativity still apply.  I don't know what this is called.

Comment: In the particular case of work and torque, work can be represented as a scalar while torque can be represented as a [bivector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector) quantity. Adding these is still technically valid in the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), but they don't "combine": if $w$ is a work scalar and $T$ a torque bivector, then from $w + T$ you can uniquely recover $w$ and $T$.

Comment: Another solution is to introduce a new unit, for example for torque. Then any formula that produces a torque will need a constant, which can be taken equal to $1$, or any other value. This constant will convert from $T^{-2}ML^2$ to the new unit. As an example of the reverse operation, we could decide to measure time in meters, and suppress the constant $c$ (light speed). Admittedly, it would not be practical for everyday life.

Comment: Note: the Wikipedia article on torque states: "Although those fundamental dimensions are the same as that for energy or work, official SI literature suggests using the unit newton-metre (N⋅m) and never the joule. The unit newton-metre is properly denoted N⋅m."

Answer (score 0):

They represent different Kinds of Quantities. Trying to analyse equations to infer whether you're dealing with a torque or a work value would be rather difficult in general, especially within large programmes. A simpler way would be to use a symbolic checker that allows for naming, and performs dimensional analysis. See https://www.scitepress.org/Link.aspx?doi=10.5220/0012318900003645

Comment: That seems to cover _algorithmic_ manipulation of units of measurement, which is a separate issue from what I was talking about. I am interested in refining the _abstract algebra_ of dimensional analysis.